# CMake, source_group used incorrectly or has incorrect behaviour?

Tags: c++, xcode, build, cmake

Using source_group in CMake to organize source files (in this case for Xcode) turned out to be more tedious than expected.

```
set(REG1 ".*/some_folder1/")
set(REG2 ".*/some_folder2/")
set(REC ".*([.]cpp|[.]c)")

source_group("src" REGULAR_EXPRESSION "${REC}" )
source_group("src\\some_group" REGULAR_EXPRESSION "${REG1}${REC}" )
source_group("src\\some_other_group" REGULAR_EXPRESSION "${REG2}${REC}" )
```

I expected the above to put all source files from some_folder1 in src/some_group in the IDE, some_folder2 in src/some_other_group, and the rest of the files directly in the src group.

However, the result is that all files go directly into the src group.

If I remove the first source_group-line and only use the two non-overlapping ones:

```
source_group("src\\some_group" REGULAR_EXPRESSION "${REG1}${REC}" )
source_group("src\\some_other_group" REGULAR_EXPRESSION "${REG2}${REC}" )
```

the behaviour is almost as intended. I.e. all files matching the two regular expressions are organized as intended, but the rest of the files go into the default "Source Files" group created by Xcode (a different IDE will have a different default folder).

So it seems like the first source_group somehow overrides the remaining two even if CMake's documentation states the opposite (excerpt from CMake's documentation on source_group):

> If a file  matches  multiple  groups,
>                 the  LAST  group  that  explicitly lists the file will be favored, if any.  If no group
>                 explicitly lists the file, the LAST group whose regular  expression  matches  the  file
>                 will be favored.

Is this due to some misunderstanding on my part or does CMake->source_group actually behave in a different way than advertised?

I am using cmake version 2.8.10 on a OSX platform.

Comment: PS. I know that in the particular example that I am giving, where the mapping is "folder -> group", the organisation can be made on the file(GLOB ...) level, but the real issue is more general than that.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, looks like source groups generates incorrectly. If you interested in workaround, you can rewrite first regex to not match other groups:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.4)
project(example_simple CXX)

file(
    GLOB
    src
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cpp"
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.c"
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/headers/*.hpp"
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/headers/*.h"
)

add_executable(simple_bin ${src})

set(REG_SRC ".*/src/")
set(REG_HDR ".*/headers/")
set(REG_EXT "[^/]*([.]cpp|[.]c|[.]h|[.]hpp)$")

source_group("src" REGULAR_EXPRESSION "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${REG_EXT}")
source_group("src\\[sources]" REGULAR_EXPRESSION "${REG_SRC}${REG_EXT}")
source_group("src\\[headers]" REGULAR_EXPRESSION "${REG_HDR}${REG_EXT}")
```

or write your own regex order and use FILES, instead of REGULAR_EXPRESSION:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.4)
project(example_simple CXX)

file(
    GLOB
    src
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cpp"
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.c"
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/headers/*.hpp"
    "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/headers/*.h"
)

add_executable(simple_bin ${src})

set(REG_SRC ".*/src/")
set(REG_HDR ".*/headers/")
set(REG_EXT ".*([.]cpp|[.]c|[.]h|[.]hpp)")

foreach(filename ${src})
  string(REGEX MATCH "${REG_SRC}${REG_EXT}" match_group_sources ${filename})
  string(REGEX MATCH "${REG_HRD}${REG_EXT}" match_group_headers ${filename})
  if(match_group_sources)
    list(APPEND group_sources ${filename})
  elseif(match_group_headers)
    list(APPEND group_headers ${filename})
  else()
    list(APPEND group_other ${filename})
  endif()
endforeach()

source_group("src" FILES ${group_other})
source_group("src\\[sources]" FILES ${group_sources})
source_group("src\\[headers]" FILES ${group_headers})
```

Comment: Well my whole CMake is not suitable to post here (also it has been modified some to solve the above problem by being more fine-grained on the file(GLOB expression). But the part handling source files is roughly as above, except I used GLOB to list the source files: `file (GLOB src     "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.cpp"       "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.c" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/headers/*.hpp" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/headers/*.h")` and then  `add_executable(${S_APP_name} ${src})`

Comment: Thanks for the effort! This is not very far from the workaround that I made myself (except I made it on the file(GLOB-level ). I am still curious to why source_group behaves differently to its documentation, but I will attribute it to a bug until further notice and take it up with the cmake community :).